# Stata remove entire word from string

Tags: stata

I have a string variable where I want to remove certain words, but many other words would be a partial match, which I don't want to remove. I want to remove words, if and only if they are a complete match.

```
clear
* Add in some example data
input index str50 words
1 "more mor morph test"
2 "ten tennis tenner tenth keeper"
3 "badder baddy bad other"
end

* I create a copy to compare obefore/after strip
gen strip_words = words

* This is a list of words I want removed. In reality, this is a fairly long list
local removs "mor ten bad"
* For each of words, remove the complete word from teh string
foreach w of local removs {
    replace strip_words = subinstr(strip_words, "`w'","", .) 
}

list
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
     | index                            words            strip_words |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1              more mor morph test            e ph test   |
  2. |     2   ten tennis tenner tenth keeper     nis ner th keeper  |
  3. |     3           badder baddy bad other         der dy other   |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried padding some spaces with `replace strip_words = " " + strip_words + " "`, but then this also removes the spaces separating the other words. My desired output would be

```
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | index                            words                      strip_words |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1              more mor morph test              more  morph test    |
  2. |     2   ten tennis tenner tenth keeper    tennis tenner tenth keeper    |
  3. |     3           badder baddy bad other           badder baddy  other    |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `help string functions` for `subinword()`.

```
clear
* Add in some example data
input index str50 words
1 "more mor morph test"
2 "ten tennis tenner tenth keeper"
3 "badder baddy bad other"
end

* I create a copy to compare obefore/after strip
gen strip_words = words

* This is a list of words I want removed. In reality, this is a fairly long list
local removs "mor ten bad"
* For each of words, remove the complete word from teh string
foreach w of local removs {
    replace strip_words = subinword(strip_words, "`w'","", .) 
}

replace strip_words = itrim(strip_words)
```

Comment: I came late with my answer (a minute or so), but I learned something new: `itrim`. However, I cannot find this function's documentation; neither `help itrim` nor `help string functions` are being useful. What am I missing here? I am only getting hits for the `stritrim()` function.

Comment: Evidently `itrim()` still works but is no longer documented (16.1). `help stritrim()` gets you to the preferred synonym.

Answer (score 2):

This can be handled with regular expressions. For an introduction: [link](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/)

Stata's Unicode-based regex commands support `\b` to indicate word boundaries.

```
clear
input index str50 words
1 "more mor morph test"
2 "ten tennis tenner tenth keeper"
3 "badder baddy bad other"
end

local rmv "(mor|ten|bad)"
gen wanted = ustrregexra(words, "\b`rmv'\b", "")
list

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | index                            words                        wanted |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1              more mor morph test              more  morph test |
  2. |     2   ten tennis tenner tenth keeper    tennis tenner tenth keeper |
  3. |     3           badder baddy bad other           badder baddy  other |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From your example it seems you want to keep spaces as above. Otherwise you can remove them with `strtrim()` and `stritrim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example but using `subinword` instead of `subinstr` you can get your desired output.

```
clear
* Add in some example data
input index str50 words
1 "more mor morph test"
2 "ten tennis tenner tenth keeper"
3 "badder baddy bad other"
end

* I create a copy to compare obefore/after strip
gen strip_words = words
gen strip_words_2 = words

* This is a list of words I want removed. In reality, this is a fairly long list
local removs "mor ten bad"
* For each of words, remove the complete word from teh string
foreach w of local removs {
    replace strip_words   = subinstr(strip_words, "`w'","", .) 
    replace strip_words_2 = subinword(strip_words_2,"`w'","",.)
    }

list
     

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | index                            words          strip_words                 strip_words_2 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1              more mor morph test           e  ph test              more  morph test |
  2. |     2   ten tennis tenner tenth keeper    nis ner th keeper    tennis tenner tenth keeper |
  3. |     3           badder baddy bad other        der dy  other           badder baddy  other |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```